# TFS build step WriteCustomSummaryInfo with Replace

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-process

How would I run "Replace" within WriteCustomSummaryInfo step.

I'm trying to display a link to an html report on the build summary:

- Get drop location which I do:

  \tfsbuild03\temp\Dev-Deployment\Dev-Deployment_20160115.22
- replace all \ with / and append **report.html** at the end

I assume this is the way to do it.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
String.Format("dotCover [Coverage Results]file:({0})/{1}", Replace(DropLocation,"\","/"), "report.html")
```

EDIT
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It's suppose to be this:

```
String.Format("dotCover [Coverage Results]file:({0})/{1}", DropLocation.Replace("\", "/"), "report.html")
```